# Did the cylons deliberately spare these characters?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004

In *Battlestar Galactica* (2004) it is eventually revealed that the

> "Final Five" cylons

are, in fact, characters in the fleet.

However, it seems like an amazing stroke of luck that all of these characters were spared when the colonies were attacked, especially considering they didn't even know they were cylons so they couldn't have conspired with the others to get out of the way.

Is there evidence that the cylons somehow knew to wait until they were all out of the way (e.g. in space) before launching their attack on the 12 planets?

Comment: **Spoilers** Well, at least in the case of Ellen Tigh, she described being thrown on the last shuttle just as it was leaving, and it's either implied or outright stated later in the series that it was Caville that put her on it.

Comment: Spoilers: iirc Samuel was in a remote part of Caprica, Tory was on Colonial 1, Tigh and Tirrol were on Galactica

Comment: @SpacePhoenix - Indeed, but it just seems incredibly lucky that they all just happened to be out of the way and my question is whether the cylons planned it that way.

Comment: It's quite likely that Cavil / One wanted it that way - punishing his mommy/daddy figures for his own self-loathing was his jam, and he couldn't torture them if they were dead.  Although he seemed more focused on the Tighs.  He could have, but whether he did or not would be an open question.

Comment: Remember that the remade BSG conveys a sense of divine intervention too. A higher presence had a plan and a reason behind everything that happened. It stands to reason they also had a plan behind the Final Five surviving as they had their role to play in the end.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that it was necessary for Cavil to make sure they survive (if the attack had been 100% successful as planned, there would have been nor survivors at all).
He had already killed them once (and resurrected them with false memories) so probably he just had spare bodies of them ready to resurrect them (this time with restored memories) so they can then mourn the extinction of mankind

> like he eventually did with Ellen in season 4.

Comment: As far as I know though, none of them at the end of the series were resurrected during the series, all are their original selves. So even if Cavil didn't (in fact, especially if he didn't) - need them to survive, it seems incredible that they all did, and made it onto the fleet.